# TFS Autobuild succeeds if manually queued but fails if scheduled

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, tfsbuild, workspace

I have a project that I upgraded from .net 2.0 to .net 4.0.

I have edited the Build definition to ensure the correct build controller is being used and edited the Build Project (and checked it back in) to update the location of devenv as follows:

```
<Exec Command="&quot;$(ProgramFiles)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\devenv&quot; &quot;$(SolutionRoot)\TBSWatcher.sln&quot; /Build &quot;Release|Any CPU&quot;"/>
```

If I manually queue a new build it succeeds but the overnight scheduled build fails.

The error log shows that it fails as it is trying to build the project using Visual Studio 2008.

```
E:\Builds\10\Tools\MyProject\BuildType\TFSBuild.proj (240): The command ""C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\devenv" "E:\Builds\10\Tools\MyProject\Sources\MyProject.sln" /Build "Release|Any CPU"" exited with code 9009.
```

I'm suspecting it may be something to do with workspaces but our TFS guru is away and I'm a bit stumped.

Any ideas why this is working when I queue a build but failing when scheduled overnight?

Answer (score 1):

Use [MSBuild Task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z7f65y0d) instead of the Exec task.

```
<ItemGroup>
    <ProjectToBuild Include="E:\Builds\10\Tools\MyProject\Sources\MyProject.sln"></ProjectToBuild>
</ItemGroup>
 <Target Name="Build">
    <MSBuild Projects="@(ProjectToBuild)" Properties="Configuration=Release;Platform=AnyCPU"/>
</Target>
```

Answer (score 0):

it seems, that build fails before running your exec command.
in this case you could check that imports added to your E:\Builds\10\Tools\MyProject\BuildType\TFSBuild.proj file.
anyway you should get rid of using exec task.

Comment: It certainly seems getting rid of the EXEC task is the way to go but what makes you think it is failing before it gets to the EXEC task?

Comment: your exec line refers to "Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0" but errors says about "Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0", thus you paste wrong error line or error was happen not in the exec task.

Comment: Not a copy and paste error this is the issue I am trying to fix. I updated the build project and checked it back in but I can the "Visual studio 2009" error however double clicking on that line takes me to the build project file with the line reading "Visual Studio 2010"

Comment: thus, you have two build definitions. are you have fixed both of them?